# Avoid calling remote url again on typeahead:selected

Tags: bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead

I have my code working like this :

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    name: 'users',
    valueKey: 'name',
    remote: {
      url: 'usersList/%QUERY', //service to get only user's id and name
      filter: function(data) {
          var resultList = data.map(function (item) {
          return item;
      });
      return resultList;
      }
    }       
  }).on('typeahead:selected', function(t, d) {
    //cal another service to get all details of selected user
  });
```

I don't want to load all the user data from the typeahead's remote url, because data associated with each user is huge, and all that work will be of no use since im going to select just one user from the list suggested.

So i have created another service, which takes the user id and gets all the data for that id, which i want to call on select. This also works fine, but my problem is this : once i select the user, i see a call to the remote url again : `userList/<full user name>`. This is unwanted. How do i avoid this on select?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug/feature in Typeahead.
I think my Svakinn fork has this issue resolved though:
https://github.com/Svakinn/typeahead.js/tree/typeaheadSimple

You could also use the **Handler** option to get better control on the remote data lookup.